# How to paste text in Pastebin using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, pastebin, tampermonkey

I'm using Tampermonkey (the same as Greasemonkey, but for Chrome) to make a script. The idea is to paste the text I write into Pastebin. The text was written in other website. I saw I can do it using GM_xmlhttpRequest, but it doesn't work. 
This is my code:

```
    var charac = new Array(50);
    var i =0
function callkeydownhandler(evnt) {

   var ev = (evnt) ? evnt : event;
   var code=(ev.which) ? ev.which : event.keyCode;
   charac[i]= code;
        i++;
}
if (window.document.addEventListener) {
   window.document.addEventListener("keydown", callkeydownhandler, false);
} else {
   window.document.attachEvent("onkeydown", callkeydownhandler);
}

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://pastebin.com/post.php",
  data: "user=mysuser&password=mypassword", //as you can imagine I use my credentials
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  onload: function(response) {
    alert("posted");
    document.getElementById("paste_code").value+=charac[i];
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});
```

I'm sure the two last lines are not working properly, but I don't know why. The first function works perfect.

What am I doing bad? How can I fix it?

Thank you! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I developed a simple API that does exactly what you want.

[Includes : Persist BETA](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/154322)

Pastebin has an API, but it currently doesn't support editing posts.
That is why I needed to create two different "services" specific to pastebin... PASTEBIN and PASTEBIN2

If you don't need editing, use PASTEBIN. Otherwise, use PASTEBIN2.

The first thing you will need is an [Unique Developer API Key](http://pastebin.com/api#1).
Then you will need an [User API Key](http://pastebin.com/api/api_user_key.html).

Here are some examples of usage of my script:

**Creating a new post**

```
Persist.write({
    service : "PASTEBIN",
    value   : "...",
    data    : {
        api_dev_key     : "...",
        api_user_key    : "...",
    },
    onload  : function (result) {
        alert("http://pastebin.com/" + result.key);
    }
});
```

**Editing an existing post**

```
Persist.write({
    service : "PASTEBIN2",
    mode    : -1,   // prepend
    key     : "..."
    value   : "...",
    data    : {
        api_dev_key     : "...",
        api_user_key    : "...",
    },
    onload  : function (result) {
        alert("Post #" + result.key + "\nNew value: " + result.value);
    }
});
```

**Reading an existing post**

```
Persist.read({
    service : "PASTEBIN",
    key     : "..."
    data    : {
        api_dev_key     : "...",
        api_user_key    : "...",
    },
    onload  : function (result) {
        alert("\nValue: " + result.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It works really well. However I have some questions: can I post private pastes? 
And, the function starts when you load the page. How can I invoke it when I press spacebar or enter key?

Comment: Yes, I recommend you to read the [Pastebin API](http://pastebin.com/api#7). Then add your desired parameters to "data".

Comment: PASTEBIN works but editing with PASTEBIN2 (same dev and user keys) gets an error in console: Array[2]
0: "request.error