# Want my Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey script to store data to the office network drive

Tags: jquery, sqlite, greasemonkey, network-drive, tampermonkey

What is the best way to store data to a local network drive, so that my Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey script can be used by everyone at my office?

And if its possible, i would like to be able to do this in Jquery.

I do not have a webserver running at my office either, only network drive that is accessible for everyone.

Can i for example store variables and data as .txt or to a SQLite database? or any other ways?

By network drive i mean, ie: "//hostname/sharename" or "N:/foldername"

Not sure if this is something i can use, but i guess not, since it seems to only give access to a sandboxed area i think: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: Duplicate of [Save File using Greasemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951149/save-file-using-greasemonkey), and [Storing into file using JavaScript/GreaseMonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6392103/331508), and others.

Comment: Chrome, userscript file IO is sandboxed.  Your web drive might have an optional web interface.  If not, you must set up a local server or use Google doc/drive, or similar service on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use a WebDAV client for javascript, to edit stuff on the "network drive",
maybe this will work? https://github.com/sara-nl/js-webdav-client

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do the way you want, but you can use for example [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) to store data and then retrieve it by the script from time to time.

Consider reading [How to paste text in Pastebin using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15315815/157873)
This question is "how to paste", but the answer shows "how to read" too.

The problem with Pastebin is that it stops working when is under heavy load.