# Edit a PasteBin using js and then read it

Tags: javascript, pastebin

I have a variable i want to store in a pastebin so i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313063/how-to-paste-text-in-pastebin-using-javascript) but the link to the API isn't working.

I was wondering if it would be possible to store a variable in a pastebin file so when you go to the site on another computer it gets the value from pastebin and makes it the variable

e.g.

`var posts = <Link to pastebin>`

user makes a post so it edits the pastebin

so when another user gets on the site they can see what the other user post.

Comment: Surely there will be a way doing that. Have you tried using the API (http://pastebin.com/api/)?

Comment: that does not let you edit or read, only create.

Comment: At least, in the JS-API-Wrapper (https://github.com/j3lte/pastebin-js) listed here (http://pastebin.com/tools#pastebinnode) there is the `getPaste`-method which allows reading.

Comment: Might use that. Now i just need to find a way to write to a pastebin

Comment: There is another node-module out there: https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-pastebin. It seems to provide possibilities to edit pastes. I did not find any other information on how to edit pastes using the api - maybe you can try deleting and re-creating the paste on every change.

Comment: nice! I have 0 idea how to use it though

Comment: Just try and return if you got details. Then please add your code and detailled error messages / problem descriptions.

Comment: Alternatively you could use Google Drive, for storing such variable.

Comment: How would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no API for editing pastes directly.

You can create or delete them using the api (wrappers for JS exist [here](https://github.com/j3lte/pastebin-js) and [here](https://github.com/Hydrothermal/better-pastebin), API docs are provided [here](http://pastebin.com/api/)). There are lots of other examples on how to use the api listed [here](http://pastebin.com/tools).

If you do not use the node modules listed above, you can have a look into that code at [here](https://github.com/Hydrothermal/better-pastebin/blob/master/lib/better-pastebin.js) - they do not use the api for editing, they do post the forms manually.